# Python - Error to simple copy .csv file

Tags: python, csv, shutil

I'm only using shutil.copyfile to copy a .csv from a network path to a local path:

```
from shutil import copyfile
import os.path
import _datetime as dt

fileCsv = "VDOCUMENT.csv"

srcPath = r"\\reports\"
dstPath = r"C:\Audit1\"

copyfile(os.path.join(srcPath, fileCsv), os.path.join(dstPath, fileCsv))
```

## The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/cvmsouz/Desktop/test/00_MoveCSV.py", line 16, in <module>
copyfile(os.path.join(srcPath, fileCsv), os.path.join(dstPath, fileCsv))
File "C:\Users\cvmsouz\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\reports\\VDOCUMENT.csv'
```

Comment: have you tried to open `\\reports\VDOCUMENT.csv` manually?

Comment: Something looking odd with four backslashes "\\\\" maybe try srcPath = r"reports\"

Comment: What is \\reports? Network folder or relative folder?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, the path is online

Comment: @Rahul \\reports is a network folder

Comment: @L.S. There are four backslashes because when you put four backslashes in a normal Python string, they evaluate to two backslashes. And a filename starting with two backslashes looks like a Windows network share, so I think that bit is fine. It's just that the file doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Daaaamn, the network file has a different name. Well thanks to you all, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually dumb: the network file has a different name than the local file.

If there's something to learn because it's good for everybody is to create standards people.